# Quantile probability (QP) plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a quantile probability (QP) plot by ggplot2 where, rather than represented by a single dot, all observations of the same value are shown individually. What I try to do is a ggplot2 version of the `qpplot.das` function from the StatDA package.

Example: The following code:

```
library(StatDA)
data(chorizon)
As <- chorizon[,"As"] 

qpplot.das(log10(As), qdist = qnorm, xlab = "As (ppm)", logx = TRUE, line = FALSE)
```

produces this plot;
[StatDA::qpplot.das](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izBjZ.png), where all observations (concentrations) at for instance 0.1 ppm are 'stacked'.

I am sure there is a ggplot2 way for this plot and I am very grateful for any help on this matter. My best attempt so far is:

```
library(ggplot2)
pbreaks <- c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, .10, .30, .50, .70, .90, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999)

ggplot() +
 geom_point(aes(As), stat = "ecdf") +
 scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::probability_trans("norm"),
                    breaks = pbreaks,
                    labels = prettyNum(pbreaks*100)) +
 scale_x_log10()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)

pbreaks <- c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, .10, .30, .50, .70, .90, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999)

chorizon %>% 
  arrange(As) %>% 
  mutate(prob = cumsum(As / sum(As))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(As, prob)) +
  geom_point(shape = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::probability_trans("norm"),
                     breaks = pbreaks,
                     labels = prettyNum(pbreaks*100)) +
  scale_x_log10()
```